# Would animals from Earth be able to survive and reproduce on this planet?

Tags: planets, fauna, habitability

Some details about the planet and its moon plus the host star.

Star: 0.85 Sol, 0.54% of the Sun's luminosity

Planet: 0.04926 (M⊕)
4836 km, 0.34 G, Orbits the host star at 0.901 AU.

The atmospheric pressure on this planet is 0.20% of the Earth's which consists of:

85.4% O2, 9.16% CO2, 3.89% N2, 1.2% SO2, H20: 332 ppm.

Moon: 0.002 (M⊕) 
770 km, 0.12 G, Semi major axis of the moon is 26415 km. Orbital  eccentricity of the moon is 0.031.

Comment: I doubt that planet would have an atmosphere that is possible to breathe... mars is 0.107 M⊕, and we can't even use parachutes....   Maybe water bears?

Comment: Is that a typo for your atmospheric pressure? If not, i don't think any thing (apart from maybe bacteria) could breathe there

Comment: @Burki Well, 0.049 Earth masses and 0.20% surface atmospheric pressure does sound about right to a first order approximation.

Comment: Stephanie, while I can appreciate that you probably made an honest mistake in this case, **it really isn't considered good form to make such a drastic change as you did** (0.20% of Earth atmospheric pressure to 20%) **after answers have been posted.** At that point, if you realize you've made a mistake like that, it would be better to post an entirely new question because **the answer is going to be *completely* different**. I won't roll back the edit unilaterally right away (I could), but I *really* encourage you to roll back your edit, and then post a new question with the corrected premise.

Comment: The planet is also going to be very, very cold if the star really has 0.54% of Sol's luminosity. Or did you mean 54%? You do have to get these numbers right if you want sensible answers.

Comment: @JohnDallman The luminosity is now 54% $L_\odot{}$. I'm rolling this back to the original revision because there is no way we can answer a moving target. Stephanie, I recommend that you post a **new** question that fixes the issues identified with this question, showing that you have learned something from this one, instead of repeatedly making answer-invalidating edits.

Comment: Please read [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) - it shows how frustrating are changes for people who answer.

Answer (score 8):

Atmospheric pressure 0.20% of that on Earth's surface?

Take a look at the [phase diagram for water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page)#Phase_diagram):

[image]

0.20% of 1 atmosphere pressure means about 2 millibar. At that pressure, liquid water cannot exist; at about -20 degrees C, it sublimates from ice to vapour. At that pressure, below -20C, water is a solid; above -20C, it is a vapour.

No higher life on Earth is equipped to deal with such conditions.

It is possible that some extremophiles may be able to *survive* by hibernating, but I very much doubt that they will be able to reproduce under such conditions.

So the answer is **no, animals from Earth would not be able to survive and reproduce under such conditions.**

And that's before we even consider the composition of the atmosphere.

In order to be able to have the three phases of water that we are used to (solid, liquid and vapour) the temperature and pressure have to be between the triple point and the critical point, so somewhere in the range 611.657 Pa (at no less than 273.16 K) to 22.064 MPa (at no more than 647 K).

Comment: @tuskiomi The tardigrade is a member of the group extremophiles. And I still doubt they would be able to reproduce, so even they fail at least one of the OP's two criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Obviously, what is being asked is about a planet with 20% of Earth's atmospheric pressure, and its sun with 54% of Sol's luminosity. A question about a planet with 0.2% of Earth's atmospheric pressure, orbiting a sun with 0.54% of Sol's luminosity wouldn't be even minimally interesting, as the obvious answer would be, **NO**, too little air, too little light.

I think that your atmospheric pressure is too low for most forms of Earthan animal life; the atmospheric pressure at Mount Everest is about 30% that of sea level, and it is irrespirable for people. At least, it would be certainly lethal without previous adaptation.

But the biggest problem, that you would have to handwave, or to create an elaborate explanation for, is that a planet with so much oxygen must necessarily already have some kind of life - of photosynthetic life, to be precise. This means that a huge problem for xenoorganisms there - supposing they could physically survive - would be their interaction with the local ecological system. Plants could be toxic, microorganisms could be pathogenic.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the incorrect percentages in the question, there's not enough nitrogen. There's less than 1% as much as in the Earth's atmosphere, so there's going to be nothing like enough available for plants. Earth animals might survive, but only if you import all their food from off-world.